# Attaching a device driver to multiple peripehral drivers in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

We are writing a device driver for ADC. The ADC uses 2 communication buses: SPI for control and McASP for data. So we need to attach the ADC driver to those bus drivers. 
For know in device tree the ADC is a child node of SPI controler. Is it possible to reference the ADC node under McASP controller as well, i.e. do something like this:

```
spi1: spi@xx{
    ..
    adc: adc@x {
        ...
    }
}
mcasp: mcasp@yy{
    ...
    &adc
}
```

Or is there in kernel some `attach()` function? 
What is the proper way of solving this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I understand concept of Device Tree, you need to provide a phandle to secondary bus. Let's assume you have an SPI device (by control) and main bus is SPI. So, inside SPI device description you need to add a phandle to the data bus.

Comment: Thanks, I get the concept of phandle. But still struggling how to translate the phandle to device structure (struct dev) of the data bus? Or vice versa, how to reference the SPI device from data bus driver?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can use the combination of functions `of_parse_phandle()` and `of_find_device_by_node()` 
There are also a family of `of_find_*` functions to use.